# Open WP Insert/Edit Link modal inside the Customizer

Tags: php, javascript, theme-customizer

Is there a way to call the WP Insert/Edit Link modal when inside the Wordpress Theme Customizer? I am trying to make a custom control button that will open up the WP Insert/Edit Link modal, instead of using the basic URL input type.

I would appreciate any assistance you can provide!

```
// Create Custom Control
class WP_Add_Link_Customize_Control extends WP_Customize_Control {
  public $type = 'add_link';
  public function render_content() { ?>
    <button class="button button-primary" onclick="OPEN INSERT/EDIT LINK MODAL"><?php _e('Add Link'); ?></button>
  <?php }
}

// Add Customizer Section
$wp_customize->add_section('btn', array(
    'title' => __('Button'),
    'priority' => 2,
    'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
    'panel' => 'hero'
));

// Add Customizer Setting
$wp_customize->add_setting('btn_link', array(
    'type' => 'theme_mod',
    'capability' => 'edit_theme_options'
));
$wp_customize->add_control(
    new WP_Add_Link_Customize_Control(
      $wp_customize,
      'btn_link',
      array( 
        'label' => __('Add Link'),
        'section' => 'btn',
      )
    )
);
```